# Limiting characters for a text area

Tags: php, textarea, character, limit

I have an options panel and in this options panel I have a text area with the id 'mytheme_about_me'.

I would like to limit the characters for this text area. I've found many jQuery solutions but because the text area is not in the same php page as my index.php, I can't use jQuery. So I'm wondering how I could do this using php?

Comment: *but because the text area is not in the same php page as my index.php, I can't use jQuery* ..... doesn't make any sense

Comment: Are you asking how to validate the length of the text in PHP after the form has been submitted, or how to validate it as the user's typing it in (via javascript)?

Comment: You can use jQuery everywhere. Just include the jquery script just like you are including it on index.php.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `maxlength` attribute, which is now supported (for `textarea` too) by major browsers. Just note that browsers may calculate line breaks differently (each break as 1 or 2 characters).
(I suppose the question is about client-side checking. Server-side checking should not be a problem.)

Comment: +1 - No need for JS. For support, check: http://wufoo.com/html5/attributes/03-maxlength.html - unfortunately it's only available in IE10+ …

Answer (score 1):

html way:
just add the `maxlenght` to your html input so it'll prevent adding characters at 20, for exemple. `<input type="text" name="whatever" maxlength="20">`. This is not safe because any user can modify this code and change the character limit, don't forget to run a php test.

php way :
 Use `strlen($yourstring)` to know the lenght of your string so you can specify a limit, don't forget that by php i mean "server sided scripting" so this test will be executed on your server, preventing the client to hack your code.

```
if (strlen($yourstring) <= 25)
// Save the input value
else
   echo 'your input is too long (25 characters max)';
```

PS : you can't access your jquery.js because you need to include it on EVERY .php page you are using, not only the index.php

Answer (score 1):

Never the less, you can do it in "plain" javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function limit(max) {
    var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
    if (textarea.value.length > max) {
        textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0, max);
    } 
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<textarea id="textarea" onkeydown="limit(10);">bla bla</textarea>
```

call `limit()` with the max number of characters you will allow

Comment: Nice one  .. but i can always disable java script or inject the text via headers ...

Comment: @Baba How could you inject text via headers?

Comment: If anyone disables javascript, then they are out of scope anyway. Inject the text ...?